# UITableView is not showing inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have in my View a long UIScrollView (about 1000 px in height), and at the end of this UIScrollView I have a UITableView.

The cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called (surely i checked the delegate and datasource if they are connected right, and the IBOutlet of the table is strong) but numberOfRowsInSection is getting called.

I tried reloading the TableView when the UIScrollView scrolls so when the table is at focus the cellForRowAtIndexPath might get called, but with no luck.

Did anyone encounter a similar behaviour when trying to use tableview and scrollview together?

Comment: Is your numberOfRowsInSection returning 0 by any chance?

Comment: No i manually return 2 to be sure

Comment: what about number of sections?

Comment: why do you set a tableview in a scrollview, that's terrible,  you can simply set a tableHeaderView to a tableview to make the same result

Comment: Why add table inside scrollview?It can cause unexpected problems.apply strictly says not to do so

Comment: I also return 1 manually for number of sections.

Comment: I need UIScrollView because i use the scroll horizontal functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hierarchy is like this:

A parentView is there. Inside the parent view there is a scroll view and there is a table view. So, your tableview is somewhere at 1000 from origin of parentview.

So, tableview will never become visible to your parentview and no delegates will be fired.

Comment: even when you scroll down, the location of the table to the parent will remain 1000?

Comment: yes..thats why it is not appearing. Its the scrollview which is scrolling not your tableview.

Comment: Thanks man, it's a hopeless case then, better find a new design.

Comment: don't go for new design. tableview.headerview = yourscrollview; dnt add scrollview into your parentview. it will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Include your view as a headerView of your UITableView like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2020, swift 5.X. To create a custom UITableView that allows your `tableview` inside a `scrollview`!

1) Create a subclass of UITableView:

import UIKit

final class ContentSizedTableView: UITableView {
    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    layoutIfNeeded()
    return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
}
```

}
2) Add a UITableView to your layout and set constraints on all sides. Set the class of it to ContentSizedTableView.

3) You should see some errors, because Storyboard doesn't take our subclass' `intrinsicContentSize` into account.  At runtime it will use the override in our ContentSizedTableView class